# Which of Moshe Chaim Luzzatto's works influenced Chassidut, Mussar, and Haskalah?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, ramchal

In [Dovid Cohen (known as Rav Ha-Nazir)'s Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cohen_%28rabbi%29), the following idea is attributed to him:

> He saw in [Moses Hayyim Luzzatto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Hayyim_Luzzatto) the harbinger of this redemption, pointing out that the three significant movements, [Hasidism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasidism), [Musar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mussar_movement), and [Haskalah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskalah), had each made certain of Luzzatto's works their classics

I know that Messilat Yesharim was one of the works that [R' Yisroel Salanter valued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mussar_movement#Rabbi_Yisrael_Salanter) for his Mussar Movement.

Which of Ramchal's works did the Haskalah and Chassidut movement "make classic"?

[Ramchal's wikipedia article says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto#Akko):

> The Hebrew writers of the Haskalah, the Jewish expression of the Enlightenment, greatly admired Luzatto's secular writings and deemed him the founder of modern Hebrew literature.

It doesn't say which work they "made classic".

Does anyone know where Rav Ha-Nazir made this statement? If it helps, here's [a link to his Hebrew wikipedia page](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_%28%D7%A8%D7%91%29).

Comment: makilim probaly his logic and play chassidm probaly derech Hashem

Comment: @simchastorah: but which of his sefarim?

Comment: Dovid Cohen seems to be a very popular name among rabbis...

Comment: Sefer HaHigayon ("The Book of Logic") lays out the correct way to think and analyze

Comment: @simchastorah: see the addition to my question

Comment: this i would imagine http://www.benyehuda.org/ramxal/migdal_oz.html

Comment: here is a list of all his irregular stuff secular and some sacred http://www.benyehuda.org/ramxal/

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is to source the Rav's statement or to identify the other classic works. If it's the latter I've tried to do so in my answer.

Comment: @nikmasi: I'd hope the source would spell it out. I guess I'm kind of looking for both.

Answer (score 1):

The haskalah certainly valued the Ramchal's poetry, plays and other non-torah related works for their literary qualities. Chassidim reference his more kabbalistic works including 138 gates of wisdom, kinas Hashem tzavkos (found in ginzei Ramchal) and others. Though I'm not aware of any work they would deem as "classic".